# Does Seaborn distplot not support a range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an array of data, called data1, that contains values from 0 to more than a thousand. I only want to have a histogram and a KDE of those values from 0 to 10. Hence I wrote:

```
sns.distplot(data1, kde=True, hist=True, hist_kws={"range": [0,10]})
plt.show()
```

What I get however is a histogram of all values (well into 2000s).

Comment: @imaluengo: `bins=` only affects the _number_ of bins if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yep it does. I had mistaken the question (so I removed the comment :P). Find a *maybe* valid answer bellow, if I did understand the problem properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just filter your data and call `displot` over the filtered data:

```
filtered = data1[(data1 >= 0) & (data1 < 10)]
sns.distplot(filtered, kde=True, hist=True, hist_kws={"range": [0,10]})
plt.show()
```

Assuming `data1` is a numpy array.

Comment: Hi, Imanol. What if I have values from 1 to 10 and I want to draw a histogram in the range of [-5, 100].  The filtering method is not going to work.

Comment: should not use this method. You have changed the data, which will give a different probability density function.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a range for `Axes` object that `sns` returns.

```
ax = sns.distplot(data1, kde=True, hist=True, hist_kws={"range": [0,10]})
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
```

Comment: ax = sns.distplot(data1, kde=True, hist=True)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
will work

Answer (score 1):

It does, just put plt.xlim(x,x1) in a line after declaring the plot and the resultant plot would only have the x values between x and x1. You can do the same for the y axis using ylim.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the KDE and histogram to be computed only for the values in [0,10] you can use the arguments `kde_kws={"clip":(0,10)}, hist_kws={"range":(0,10)}`:

```
sns.distplot(data1, kde=True, hist=True, kde_kws={"clip":(0,10)}, hist_kws={"range":(0,10)})
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `binrange` of `histplot`.

This works in modern `seaborn` too (note that **`distplot` is depreciated).

```
binrange: pair of numbers or a pair of pairs
Lowest and highest value for bin edges; 
can be used either with bins or binwidth. Defaults to data extremes.
```

Comment: Correct, try something like:

sns.displot(data1, kde=True, binrange=(0,10))